# Design CFG for language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I am given the language:

$L = $ {${a^{n+m} b^{m+k}a^kb^n | m,n,k > 0 }$}

And i am asked to design a Context Free Grammar for this language. Can anyone help me in this one? Like if there is a step by step guide that i should follow? I am new and i don't know many things about CFG's. Please if you think that my question is too general please don't down-vote, please tell me where to go, like find a tutorial somewhere because i have seen a few in YouTube and i didn't find anything that would help me in this kind of CFG.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by grouping the expression into $a^n (a^m b^m) (b^k a^k) b^n$. This reduces the pattern to $a^n$ plus a string of the form $a^m b^m$ plus a string of the form $b^k a^k$ plus $b^n$.

You can specify a string of the form $a^m b^m$ by considering "adding $a$ to the left and $b$ to the right" as one step, and use the specification to be strings you can build using that step any times to the empty string. Explicitly:

$$T \to aTb ~|~ \epsilon$$

The other steps to building $L$ can be done similarly.

Comment: So i have come up with this solution:

$S→aTb$   |

$T→NM$   | 

$N→aYb$   |

$M→bZa$   |

$Y→aYb | ϵ$   |

$Z→bZa | ϵ$  

It looks good to me. Can you give it a look and tell me if it seems correct to you?

Comment: Well you can reduce it to $S \to aNMb ~//~ N \to aNb|ab ~//~ M \to bMa|ba$.

Comment: There is one more which i cannot figure out. I am given the language
$L = $ {${a^k b^k | k > 0 }$}* and i need to find the regular expression. I guess that it will be similar to the previous one but the kleene star there confuses me as i don't know how is the information supposed to be saved in order to be repeated

Comment: Ask a new question in a new thread.

Comment: Done https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4047927/cfg-for-a-language

Comment: Hey can you check this question?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049285/create-pda-from-language
@Kenny Lau