# CFG for a Language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I am given the language:

$L = $ {${a^kb^k | k > 0 }$}*

And i am asked to design a Context Free Grammar for this language. Can anyone help me in this one? Like if there is a step by step guide that i should follow? I'm kind of confused with the kleene star in the end as i don't know how is the information supposed to be saved in order to be repeated. I am new and i don't know many things about CFG's. Please if you think that my question is too general please don't down-vote, please tell me where to go, like find a tutorial somewhere because i have seen a few in YouTube and i didn't find anything that would help me in this kind of CFG.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have to save anything. If $L_0=\{a^kb^k:k>0\}$, your $L$ is simply $L_0^*$, the language of all finite strings of words in $L_0$. Thus, besides the empty word you get all words in $L_0$, all words in $L_0^2$, and so on. For instance, you get $aabb$, $abaaabbb$, and $abaabbabaaabbb$. If you can design a CFG for $L_0$, it takes only a *very* minor addition to convert it to a CFG for $L$, so I would begin by working on a CFG for $L_0$; there is one with only two productions.

Comment: Doesnt the * mean that you are only able to have for example "aabbaabbaabb..,abababab...,aaabbbaaabbb...,"? What you described is that each time a different amount of a's and b's can be generated. Can you please clarify this to me?

Comment: @ChrisCosta: I thought that that was probably your misconception. No, the star means that you can concatenate any finite number of arbitrary members of $L_0$.

Comment: In that case i think that $S→ aNbN | ε$ // $N→ aNb | ε$ would work. What do you think?

Comment: @ChrisCosta: That generates $\{\epsilon\}\cup L_0\cup L_0^2$ (once you change $0$ to $a$ and $1$ to $b$); it doesn’t generate $L_0^n$ for any $n>2$. I would include a production $S\to SS$.

Comment: Oh okay i see my mistake, $S→ SS | aNb| ε$ // $N→ aNb | ε$  . With the production you mentioned i guess that it can be generated n times where n is the times ($S→ SS$ is chosen) -1. Is that correct?

Comment: @ChrisCosta: The grammar looks okay. It will give you a concatenation of $n+1$ words in $L_0$ if you use $S\to SS$ $n$ times and don’t use $S\to\epsilon$ at all.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Appreciate your help!

Comment: @ChrisCosta: You’re welcome!